# HTML Form/PHP and MySQL email notification

Tags: php

complete beginner at PHP and was wanting a little direction for a website I am creating. I want the admin of the website to receive an email with all of the form information aswell as it being stored in the database. The database is storing the information fine, just need an email notification. How is this achieved. My PHP code is:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');
$product = $_POST['product'];
$productcomments = $_POST['productcomments'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$delivery = $_POST['delivery'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO orderform(product, productcomments, name, address, age, delivery)VALUES('$product', '$productcomments', '$name','$address', '$age', '$delivery')");
header("location: google.com");

$to      = 'j_bussey@live.co.uk';
$subject = 'Order';
$message = 'Product: ' . $product . '<br /> Product Comments: ' . $productcomments . '<br /> ';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: There is a PHP function called mail() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: That's not the question he is asking about, but instead of replying with a sarcastic comment, how about show him the correct way to do it? He said he was new at PHP... look at my a answer for the correct solution.

Comment: I decided to put google in there as I didnt want to disclose the URL of the website I am working on. THanks for all genuine responses. Appreciated! I will give it a try!

Comment: You're also going to want to put the `header('Location')` under the `mysql_close($con)`

Answer (score 0):

this is the very basic example of mail function. read more about [mail() manual](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) here.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Email Subject";
$message = "Email Message Body";

mail($email, $subject, $message, "from: admin@yourdomain.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an awesome mail() function. I'm taking this from the documentation page here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

So since you're already grabbing the variables, you would just edit the `$message` variable in the code above to look something like this:

```
$message = 'Product: ' . $product . '<br /> Product Comments: ' . $productcomments . '<br /> ';
```

etc, etc. If you don't want to assume that they have html emails enabled, you would use `\n` instead of `<br />`

Edit:
You also need to change your `header('Location: google.com');` to `header('Location: http://www.google.com');` or wherever you want to redirect after the email has been sent off.

Comment: I have added the code in as you suggested and changed the email addreess, however I am not receiving an email. I have updated code in OP. THanks

Comment: Are you hosting the code somewhere or are you testing this on a local web server? And if so, what kind of web server?

Comment: Okay, you need to make sure that your `php.ini` file has all of the details it needs to access the mail server. Check this out: http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm

Comment: I have a contact form on my website which sends an email when a user leaves a message. I receieve those emails no problem, so I am assuming you of the details are correct in php.ini

Comment: I have just received an email. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Right on. Make sure to click the checkmark next to my answer so that others who see this question know what to do to fix whatever problems they're having.

Comment: $message = 'Product: ' . $product . '/n Product Comments: ' . $productcomments . '/n Name: ' . $name . '/n Address: ' . $address . '/n  Age: ' . $age . '/n Delivery: ' . $delivery . '/n   ';

Comment: Can you seen any mistakes in that line, I need the email to show all of the info and not just product and productcomments